How many compounds are gaseous at STP?
Wikipedia's list of gases has 545 gases at STP. This is not a complete list; for example, $\ce{SiH2ClF}$ is not listed but probably a gas because similar chemicals like $\ce{SiH2Cl2}$ and $\ce{SiH2F2}$ are gases. So how many molecules are actually reasonably stable gases at STP?
Now, there are a huge number of possible molecules with up to 17 heavy atoms, but it seems likely to me that there are fewer than around $10^{10}$ gases, because there is a limit to the number of atoms (perfluorocyclopentane has the most heavy atoms at 15, above this the molecular weight becomes too high) and to the number of "interesting" arrangements of atoms. For example, $\ce{SF6}$ has a boiling point of −63.8 °C, but $\ce{SF5OCl}$ is already up to 8.9 °C. Many functional groups create dipole moments that raise boiling points above 25 °C.
We probably can't enumerate all gases, but can we estimate the number of gases to within, say, a factor of 2?
Proposed rules:

Should be gaseous at 1 bar and 25 °C
Should be reasonably stable (perhaps a lifetime of >1 second when isolated at STP)
Isotopes don't count; otherwise there would be endless permutations of $\ce{^2H}$ and $\ce{^13C}$ in specific places


What if the hydrogen isotopes make a difference of more than the factor of 2 because most of the gases have boiling points near the upper limit, contain multiple hydrogen atoms, and the boiling point depends on whether the hydrogen is heavy or light.

Let's say something is a gas if it's a gas when the molecules are randomly constructed at standard isotopic abundances.

What about liquids with high vapor pressure at STP? For example, there is a substantial amount of water vapor above the liquid, though it is far below the B.P. Or more extreme, diethyl ether: Have you ever opened a can of ether at one end of a lab bench, while a burner is going at the other? Foof!

What is such a number good for?

The number is likely too hard to estimate reliably. The number of possible combinations is huge (even evaluating all the possible hydrocarbons with n-carbons stretches the capacity of computational chemistry somewhere around n=20). With multiple elements involved the combinatorial task is vastly harder.

@matt_black Even though there is no estimation, people still write their theories, some of which involve even more complicated parameters. For example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_theory

@PaulKolk I saw a news story about assembly theory recently that claimed it was empirically debunked. Theories are cheap; reality is complicated and rarely agrees.

@matt_black When I read the assembly theory for the first time, I thought it applies to organic chemistry pretty well, but not to anything else. Still, it is hard to imagine how they debunked it. I haven't seen these news.

@Poutnik My motivation is pure curiosity. But if one wants to know if there is a gas with property X, it would be useful to have a list of all (say) 50,000 compounds that might be gaseous in order to rule out the possibility.

I guess there should be some exhaustive list of freons, of exotic stuff, not so much.
